# .setIcon() Causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I am working on a decently long code which was working wonderfully. Out of nowhere it stopped working and I had others test it and confirmed that it was not working for them also. I also tried to rollback the code and even going a few days back nothing changed. I put a bunch of System.out.Println() to help me debug where the code was breaking and receiving the NullPointerException. It happens at initComponents(). What is more bizarre is that anything in initComponenets was generated with NetBeans as I used the GUI Builder. I had 15 lines called "Alive #" simply so I could easily see in the logs when the program crashed. Alive 14 was last I could see before crash, Alive 15 was never reached. I could only put a snippet below. https://pastebin.com/ibPfDxMY has the full initComponents(). What makes this more curious is that when running it from NetBeans it works consistiently, it only has this error when I run the .jar file via double click or terminal.

I have tried running a blank test frame and it ran perfectly fine.

```java
public class NewFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewFrame() throws IOException, NullPointerException{
        System.out.println("Alive 14");
        initComponents();
        System.out.println("Alive 15");
    }


 private void initComponents() {

        mainPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        headerPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        logoButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        titleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        logoutButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        PacketPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        exploitPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        exploitScroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        exploitList = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        customPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        customFrame = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        customScroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        customList = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        builderPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        builderFrame = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        builderPlaceholder = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        InfoPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        logPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        logScroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        logArea = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        chartPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        chartScroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        chartTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        monsterPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        monsterScroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        monsterTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        inventoryPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        inventoryScroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        inventoryList = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        bankPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        bankScroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        bankList = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        infoPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        infoFrame = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        goldValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        acValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        areaIdValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        entValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        usernameValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        areaValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        playerCountValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        playerCountLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        areaLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        usernameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        entLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        areaIdLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        acLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        goldLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        togglePane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        toggleFrame = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        afkButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        followButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        farmButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        slideButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        invisibleButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        copyButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        copyLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        invisibleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        slideLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        farmLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        followLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        afkLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        afkValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        followValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        farmValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        slideValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        invisibleValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        copyValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        SettingsPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        settingsFrame = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        userLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        emoteLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        settingsSubmitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        delayLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        loopLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        settingsSpamButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        emoteList = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        loopField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        userField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        delayField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        ChatPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        chatScroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        chatArea = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Yumemi");
        setUndecorated(true);

        mainPane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(30, 30, 30));
        mainPane.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(716, 567));
        mainPane.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                mainPaneMouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        mainPane.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                mainPaneMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });

        headerPane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

        logoButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        logoButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        logoButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AQWBot/Icons/icon.png"))); // NOI18N
        logoButton.setBorder(null);
        logoButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        logoButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        logoButton.setDefaultCapable(false);
        logoButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        logoButton.setFocusable(false);
        logoButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        logoButton.setIconTextGap(0);
        logoButton.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        logoButton.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);
        logoButton.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                logoButtonMouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        logoButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                logoButtonMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });

        exitButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        exitButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        exitButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        exitButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/aqwbot/Icons/close.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        exitButton.setText("X");
        exitButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        exitButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        exitButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        exitButton.setIconTextGap(0);
        exitButton.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/aqwbot/Icons/close_clicked.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        exitButton.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/aqwbot/Icons/close_hover.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        titleLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        titleLabel.setText("Yumemi");
        titleLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                titleLabelMouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        titleLabel.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                titleLabelMouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                titleLabelMouseExited(evt);
            }
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                titleLabelMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });

        logoutButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        logoutButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        logoutButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        logoutButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/aqwbot/Icons/logout.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        logoutButton.setText("L");
        logoutButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        logoutButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        logoutButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        logoutButton.setIconTextGap(0);
        logoutButton.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/aqwbot/Icons/logout_clicked.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        logoutButton.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/aqwbot/Icons/logout_hover.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        logoutButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                logoutButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout headerPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(headerPane);
        headerPane.setLayout(headerPaneLayout);
        headerPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            headerPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(headerPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(logoButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(titleLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(logoutButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(exitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        headerPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            headerPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(headerPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(headerPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(headerPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(exitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(titleLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(logoutButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(logoButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(0, 9, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        exploitList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Raw", "XP", "Say", "Whisper", "Role Play", "Emote", "", "Join", "Goto", "Move", "House", "", "Friend", "Follow", "Copy", "ID", "", "Party Chat", "Invite Party", "Remove Party", "Summon", "Promote", "Leave Party", "", "Guild Chat", "Create Guild", "Invite to Guild", "Remove from Guild", "Promote Guild", "Demote Guild", "Change MOTD", "Rename Guild", "", "Battle Commands", "", "Custom Commands", "Invisible", "Slide", "Farm", "Share Attack", "", "Staff Commands" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        exploitList.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        exploitScroll.setViewportView(exploitList);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout exploitPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(exploitPane);
        exploitPane.setLayout(exploitPaneLayout);
        exploitPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            exploitPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(exploitPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(exploitScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 330, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        exploitPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            exploitPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, exploitPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(exploitScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 208, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        PacketPane.addTab("Commands", exploitPane);

        customList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Accept Quest", "AutoComplete Quest" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        customScroll.setViewportView(customList);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout customFrameLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(customFrame);
        customFrame.setLayout(customFrameLayout);
        customFrameLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            customFrameLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(customFrameLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(customScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 340, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        customFrameLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            customFrameLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, customFrameLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(customScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 217, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout customPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(customPane);
        customPane.setLayout(customPaneLayout);
        customPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            customPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 360, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(customPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(customPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(customFrame, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        customPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            customPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 229, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(customPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(customPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(customFrame, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        PacketPane.addTab("Custom", customPane);

        builderFrame.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.LOWERED));

        builderPlaceholder.setText("Accept Args and Data and Etc");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout builderFrameLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(builderFrame);
        builderFrame.setLayout(builderFrameLayout);
        builderFrameLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            builderFrameLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(builderFrameLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(66, 66, 66)
                .addComponent(builderPlaceholder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 181, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        builderFrameLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            builderFrameLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(builderFrameLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                .addComponent(builderPlaceholder)
                .addContainerGap(118, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout builderPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(builderPane);
        builderPane.setLayout(builderPaneLayout);
        builderPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            builderPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(builderPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(builderFrame, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        builderPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            builderPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(builderPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(builderFrame, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        PacketPane.addTab("Packet Builder", builderPane);

        logScroll.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(50, 50, 50));
        logScroll.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(200, 200, 200));
        logScroll.setToolTipText("");

        logArea.setEditable(false);
        logArea.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(50, 50, 50));
        logArea.setContentType("text/pl"); // NOI18N
        logArea.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(200, 200, 200));
        logScroll.setViewportView(logArea);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout logPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(logPane);
        logPane.setLayout(logPaneLayout);
        logPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            logPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(logPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(logScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 325, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        logPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            logPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(logPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(logScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 208, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        InfoPane.addTab("Packets", logPane);

        chartScroll.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(50, 50, 50));
        chartScroll.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(200, 200, 200));
        chartScroll.setToolTipText("");

        chartTable.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(50, 50, 50));
        chartTable.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(200, 200, 200));
        chartTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {}
            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        chartScroll.setViewportView(chartTable);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout chartPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(chartPane);
        chartPane.setLayout(chartPaneLayout);
        chartPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            chartPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(chartPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(chartScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 325, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        chartPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            chartPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(chartPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(chartScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 217, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        InfoPane.addTab("Chart", chartPane);

        monsterScroll.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(50, 50, 50));
        monsterScroll.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(200, 200, 200));
        monsterScroll.setToolTipText("");

        monsterTable.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(50, 50, 50));
        monsterTable.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(200, 200, 200));
        monsterTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {}
            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        monsterScroll.setViewportView(monsterTable);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout monsterPaneLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(monsterPane);
        monsterPane.setLayout(monsterPaneLayout);
        monsterPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            monsterPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(monsterPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(monsterScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 325, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        monsterPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            monsterPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(monsterPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(monsterScroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 217, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        InfoPane.addTab("Monster", monsterPane);

        inventoryList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        inventoryScroll.setViewportView(inventoryList);
```

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: When you run the jar with `java -jar <JARFILE>` in terminal/cmd you see something like [this](https://www.directupload.net/file/d/5443/x9c5tymq_jpg.htm) when the exception occurs unless you wrapped the call of the constructor in a try-catch-block or you've set a default exception handler for your application. In this case, you have to add a `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch-block/exception-handler.

Comment: And are you sure that `mainPane`, `headerPane`, `logoButton`... are fields in your class? And do the methods `logoutButtonActionPerformed()` and so one really exist?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nkluxx LogoutButtonActionPerformed() exists.
headerPane, logoButton, mainPane as well http://prntscr.com/nklve7 


We get error 
https://pastebin.com/iwaCYr8t when running in cmd

Comment: As I can see from the stacktrace, the problem is yet in the line I've mentioned in my answer (line 192 in your code). Are you sure that you've commented all the lines where you use `getResource()` out? And, stupid question, but have you exported the application to a jar again (without the lines in question) and are you sure that you launched from the new file?

Comment: This is interesting, I found one spot that I might have missed. Now upon running the .jar when calling the new frame I get an entirely blank frame, like it cannot even be seen. http://prntscr.com/nkxooe . Do you have any ideas for this? Upon looking closely the frame is going to 1,1 for some reason and all components are hidden, this is bizarre. At this point I can get the JFrame to be visible however none of the JPanel's or any other UI components are showing. Well I even had to remove the images that I used from the UI Builder but it loads again, previously it worked hmm.

Comment: What is weird is that the icons do have their full path http://prntscr.com/nky25d. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, you have used the full path. But I am seeing now,  sometimes you have written „aqwbot“ instead of „AQWBot“.

Comment: What is confusing to me is the fact that these same images work in my other JFrame in the same program and it works great in that frame,  I can even copy the code from that frame and it has the same issue. hmm. That frame actually opens this frame. Does that give you any ideas? It also was working fine and stopped working with no changes, I tried to rollback the version using history and it still didn't resolve.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nlfm9b
I decided to make a test, it can read the files from the binary, and the reason that it's all lowercase is because when netbeans compiles AQWBot it makes it lowercase though in src folder it has capitals. But right here it shows that it can read the file but still crashes regardless, I can try to manually put it before or after the initComponents, with a .repaint() or not. I can try using the UI builder and same issue.
http://prntscr.com/nlfm0q

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this line causes the `NullPointerException`:

```
logoButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AQWBot/Icons/icon.png"))); // NOI18N
```

I had this issue too, and it worked for me when I passed the whole path to the image, for example: (provided that the image is located in the package `at.daselias.resources.icons`)

```
logoButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/at/daselias/resources/icons/icon.png"))); // NOI18N
```

That problem occurs always only in a jar file, but not in the IDE.

**EDIT**: Of course it's not enough to fix the issue in the line I suggested, you have to do this in all lines where you're loading resources.

Comment: It has an issue before it gets that far, however I did comment out all code grabbing resources (the only sections are for the icons) and issue persists.

Comment: As I've already commented under your question, could you please provide the stack-trace to make it easier to help you?

Comment: Yep, I am just not sure how I'd post that information, and what line do you want the breakpoint on?